# Edit docker container settings while container is running

Tags: docker

I have a docker container which is running with port mapping.

> cce2ca6eb83b        nginx                       "nginx -g 'daemon off"   5 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds               0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   www-nginx

Now I want to change host port from 80 to 8080.  How can I do that?

> docker update

does not have any option to change the network settings.

Comment: I think you should stop running container, update exported port in Dockerfile, rebuild your image and then run container again. Plus, make sure that nothing is listening on 8080 port on your host machine.

Answer (score 4):

You can't edit the port mapping for running container. `docker update` command is used to prevent containers from consuming too many resources from their Docker host and  also to dynamically set restart policy but not port mapping.

A work around for what you want to achieve could be to create a new image from your current container and then start a new container from the newly created image with the port 8080 as follow:

```
docker stop www-nginx
docker commit www-nginx www-nginx-2
docker run -p 8080:80 -td www-nginx-2
```

Comment: I was aware of this solution already but was wondering what makes docker do not allow updating of network settings after the container is created...

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the port mapping on a container, you will have to create a new container.